# Casting a dictionary value to decimal or float before sorting

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has `name: number` pairs in it.

Both the name and the number are stored as strings but the number is always cast to a decimal before use. If I try to sort the dictionary by value it is using this value as a string and then sorting it according to that rather than by its decimal representation.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
import collections
import operator
from decimal import *

TWODECIMALPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2

adict = {'fred': Decimal(6.56).quantize(TWODECIMALPLACES),
         'paul': Decimal(47.91).quantize(TWODECIMALPLACES),
         'george': Decimal(2.59).quantize(TWODECIMALPLACES),
         'ringo': Decimal(11.50).quantize(TWODECIMALPLACES),
         'john': Decimal(1.57).quantize(TWODECIMALPLACES)}
bdict = {'fred': "6.56", 'paul': "47.91", 'george': "2.59",
         'ringo': "11.50", 'john': "1.57"}

print ("adict" + str(adict) + "\n")
print ("bdict" + str(bdict) + "\n")

sadict =  sorted(adict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
sbdict =  sorted(bdict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)

print ("sadict " + str(sadict) + "\n")
print ("sbdict " + str(sbdict) + "\n")

for idx, item in enumerate(sadict):
    print (str(sadict[idx][0]) + " : " + str(sadict[idx][1]))

for idx, item in enumerate(sbdict):
    print (str(sbdict[idx][0]) + " : " + str(sbdict[idx][1]))
```

How to I cast the dictionary value to a float or decimal before sorting it so it sorts the values correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda `key` function to `sorted()`:

```
sorted(bdict.items(), key=lambda i: float(i[1]), reverse=True)
```

instead of `operator.itemgetter(1)` to turn the value into a float while sorting. The `key` argument can be any callable that takes one argument, after all.

Demo:

```
>>> bdict = {'fred':"6.56",'paul':"47.91",'george':"2.59",'ringo':"11.50",'john':"1.57"}
>>> sorted(bdict.items(), key=lambda i: float(i[1]), reverse=True)
[('paul', '47.91'), ('ringo', '11.50'), ('fred', '6.56'), ('george', '2.59'), ('john', '1.57')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I never know how to read or understand lambda functions. I have copy-pasted them a few times before and they work but I have no idea how... they aren't exactly readable.

Comment: @Zac: `lambda arguments: expr` is just like `def functionname(arguments): return expr`. So `lambda i: float(i[1])` is the same thing as `def key_function(i): return float(i[1])`, but without a name.

Comment: Changing `lambda i: float(i[1])` to `lambda i: (-float(i[1]), i[0])` and `reverse=False` you can sort in descending order of value and, in the case of ties, in alphabetic order of name. The value returned by a `key` need not be a number, it can just be something that can be ordered.